# what is "cryptographically secure page or form nonce in a hidden form field" in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, session, cryptography, session-state, nonce

I am learning about the securities which can be provided to ASP.net web applications. I came cross the terms "cryptography" and "nonce" which can provide security in session management. Kindly help me to know more about this.

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to understand what questions are considered off-topic. To summarise: you need to do your own research and ask specific questions if you don't understand something.

Comment: Okay thank you .... But if you can paste a link about the topic would be helpful

Comment: Look its as is say, you can save on the page an encrypted value, or a non encrypted... what did you not understand about that ?

Comment: @Alex This a security question applied to ASP.Net, so it is on-topic. Lack of research doesn't make it off-topic. If you find that this question is not useful, you're free to downvote the question. If you have constructive criticism, please post a specific clarification request.

Comment: It's there to prevent CSRF: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29

Comment: @Artjom B., my interpretation of this question is "recommend or find a book" as I implied in the above comment. I may be wrong of course.